# Need to get the LDAP groups for the current windows user in electron project

Tags: c#, node.js, npm, electron

I was able to get all the LDAP groups of the current windows user in my WinForm app now I am moving this app to electron and I want to do the same.

I am looking for some existing package to do this.
OR any workaround.

I have already tried the following:
1) https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory
2) https://www.npmjs.com/package/ad

But all of this needs user password to be provided.

C# code used in Winforms:

```
        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\').Last();

        IList<string> groups = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Domain.GetCurrentDomain()))
            {

                using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de))
                {
                    adSearch.Filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "(sAMAccountName={0})", userName);
                    SearchResult result = adSearch.FindOne();
                    if (result == null)
                        MessageBox.Show("null......");

                    ResultPropertyValueCollection rpCollection = result.Properties["memberof"];

                    foreach (string rp in rpCollection)
                    {
                        string[] properties = rp.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                        foreach (string property in properties)
                        {
                                groups.Add(property);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

As my application is running under the current windows user so, in C# code I will not be needing the password to get the LDAP groups.
How to do this in Node/ electron app ?